# Error using addSelect for subqueries in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Moving to Laravel 6 I try to use addSelect for subqueries and get rid of DB::raw() using, so  I try to remake request :

```
$taskList         = Task
    ::getByIsHomepage($is_homepage)
    ->getByStatus($viewedTasks)

    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tasks.leader_id')
    ->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'tasks.category_id')
    ->orderBy('tasks.' . $order_by, $order_by_direction)
    ->select(
        'tasks.*',
        'users.name as leader_name',
        'categories.name as category_name',
        'categories.slug as category_slug',
        \DB::raw(' ( select count(' . $prefix . 'events.id) from ' . $prefix . 'events where ' . $prefix . 'events.task_id = ' .
             $prefix . 'tasks.id ) as events_count')

    )
    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($tasks_per_page)
    ->get()
```

into

```
$taskList         = Task
    ::getByIsHomepage($is_homepage)
    ->getByStatus($viewedTasks)
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tasks.leader_id')
    ->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'tasks.category_id')
    ->orderBy('tasks.' . $order_by, $order_by_direction)
    ->select(
        'tasks.*',
        'users.name as leader_name',
        'categories.name as category_name',
        'categories.slug as category_slug'
    )->addSelect(['events_count' => Event::count('id')
        ->whereColumn('events.task_id', 'tasks.id')
    ])

    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($tasks_per_page)
    ->get()
```

and got error :

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function whereColumn() on integer
```

Which is the valid way ?

> ***MODIFIED***

I remade as :

```
$taskList         = Task
    ::getByIsHomepage($is_homepage)
    ->getByStatus($viewedTasks)
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tasks.leader_id')
    ->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'tasks.category_id')
    ->orderBy('tasks.' . $order_by, $order_by_direction)
    ->select(
        'tasks.*',
        'users.name as leader_name',
        'categories.name as category_name',
        'categories.slug as category_slug'

    )->addSelect(['events_count' => Event
        ::whereColumn('events.task_id', 'tasks.id')
        ->count('id')
    ])
```

and got error

```
:
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tsk_tasks.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(`id`) as aggregate from `tsk_events` where `tsk_events`.`task_id` = `tsk_tasks`.`id`)
```

and that is strange for me as I have table tsk_tasks with id field.
How to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is pretty clear here... `Event::count('id')` returns an `integer`, and you can't call `->whereColumn()` on an `integer`... You probably just need to switch the order: `Event::whereColumn(...)->count(...)` instead of `Event::count(...)->whereColumn(...)`

Comment: please, look at MODIFIED

Comment: Do you have a relationship set up between `tasks` and `events`?

Comment: `count` is similar to `get` and `first` in that it executes the query and returns a result., if you want to add a count to the select you can't avoid raw queries as far as I know

Comment: Yes, tasks and events have relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, calling `count()` will actually execute the query and return the result which isn't what you want in this case.

To achieve what you're after with `addSelect()` for the count you would need to add the raw count part of the query:

```
->addSelect([
    'events_count' => Event::selectRaw('count(*)')->whereColumn('events.task_id', 'tasks.id'),
])
```

---

That being said, I would suggest add the following to your `Task` model (if you haven't already):

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
}
```

Then you'll be able to use the [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method:

```
$taskList         = Task
    ::getByIsHomepage($is_homepage)
    ->getByStatus($viewedTasks)
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'tasks.leader_id')
    ->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', 'tasks.category_id')
    ->orderBy('tasks.' . $order_by, $order_by_direction)
    ->select(
        'tasks.*',
        'users.name as leader_name',
        'categories.name as category_name',
        'categories.slug as category_slug'
    )
    ->withCount('events') //<-- this bit
    ->get();
```